# 3-Way Switch Loop Conversion to Smart Switches

Tags: multiway-switch, smart-switch

I am planning the conversion of a “3-way switch loop” to a configuration with smart switch(es). I’m also documenting the existing configuration so that I (or my successor) can restore it.

## Questions

1. Are the wire color assignments in Figure 1 (before) appropriate?
2. Are the wire color assignments in Figures 2 and 3 appropriate? Would you find swapping red and black less confusing? My goal is to give flexibility between Figures 2 and 3 without changing the ceiling fixture.
3. Changing from Figure 2/3 back to Figure 1 involves removing neutral from a switch location. Is this technically a code violation? Or will it be clear that the work is restoring the original configuration? I suppose this question would only come up if I am not around to do the work.

## Figure 1 - Current Configuration

[image: wiring diagram of Current Configuration]

## Figure 2 - Smart Switch

[image: wiring diagram of Smart Switch]

## Figure 3 - Twice as Smart

[image: wiring diagram of an even better Smart Switch]

## Notes

Figure 3 has the disadvantage relative to Figure 2 that a hub is required for the garage switch to operate the light. I accept that there are enough other lights in the area to cover an emergency situation when the hub is down.

I am using a [Zooz ZEN32 switch](https://www.thesmartesthouse.com/products/zooz-700-series-z-wave-plus-scene-controller-switch-zen32). It will toggle the load when the traveler changes between open and your choice of neutral or hot.

The location is Virginia.

Comment: What do the instructions say?

Comment: The instructions don't cover the case with the light between the two switches. However, my Figure 2 is equivalent to an example where the far switch either connects the traveler to neutral or disconnects it. Figure 3 is just treating the left switch like a single pole switch. Thinking about it, the red vs black question doesn't really matter. I think the only special thing about black is that it's in every cable, while red is only in a /3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure 1 is faulty - can't ever use white as a switched-hot.   But it's leaving anyway, so whatevs :)

However the other diagrams look fine.

#3 could work.  Look harder for smart switch remotes that can talk to their companion master without a hub. Those are a thing.